# Getting values from a template execution

Tags: templates, go

I have a HTML template that I execute passing a map[string]string variable. The template uses the variable to create the HTML output that I send to clients.

In addition to producing the HTML, I would like to use the very same template to generate some values that are retured to the main program, so I can use the same file to put some logic externally.

As far as I know, it is not possible to modify the variable I pass to Execute (something like `{{.output = "value"}}`).

So how could I get multiple output values from a template Execution?

Comment: it could be easier to generate the values you need in your main program then pass them to the template, instead of trying to generate them in the template and return them to the caller...

Comment: Yes, it would be easier, but in that case, I would have to modify the program and compile it everytime I want to change the behaviour. This way, it can be done externally by someone else who knows how to create templates but not how to program in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to pass a funcmap, just pass the struct.

```
var tmpl = template.Must(template.New("test").Parse(`Before: {{.Data}}{{.Set "YY"}}, after: {{.Data}}`))

func main() {
    c := &CustomData{"XX"}
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, c)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/2eLSFoTdtn)

<strike>You can always pass a [`FuncMap`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#FuncMap) to the template, here's an extremely simple example:</strike>

```
const tmpl = `Before: {{.Data}}{{.Set "YY"}}, after: {{.Data}}`

type CustomData struct {
    Data string
}

func (c *CustomData) Set(d string) string { // it has to return anything
    c.Data = d
    return ""
}

func main() {
    c := &CustomData{"XX"}
    funcMap := template.FuncMap{
        "Set": c.Set,
    }
    t, _ := template.New("test").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(tmpl) // don't ignore errors in real code
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, c)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/-MRe1sK3pA)